# How to prevent user to delete more than 2 rows at the same time

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgis

QGIS 3.22 & PostgreSQL 14.

Many colleagues insert features in a Postgres/PostGIS database using QGIS and **import/export to PostgreSQL** database plugin.
Among many parameters, there is `add` to or `replace` the database table. Of course, I never want the table being replaced with new features, I only want the features to be added.
To prevent the table to be completely replaced, I was assuming that replace was a synonyme for delete (?). So I was trying to create a trigger with a function that counts the number of features to be deleted and raises an exception if it is greater than 2 for example.
Is it a right way to proceed? (for now nohing works but maybe because of a misuse of get diagnostics if I am in the right direction)

Comment: Can you map the action in QGIS to a stored procedure instead of directly against the table (which is generally a bad idea on its own, tbh) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html

Comment: A trigger like that will work, but if I were you, I'd first investigate what action "replace" is on the database side.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it is not "replace" according to the doc, the correct word is [overwrite](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html). I guess I have to find a way to prevent that. In fact it is **not** a delete.

Comment: Only a superuser can drop a table, and there is no superuser but me. So problem solved.

Comment: That's not true: the owner of a table can drop it.

Comment: You are right. It was a shortcut for me because the superuser owns the table.